# When a classes and its derived class have a method with the same name and signature, this is an example of:

Tags: java, overloading, overriding

I know that you uy are very busy but if you can help me it will be a great help. I have a question When a classes and its derived class have a method with the same name and signature, this is an example of:

```
A.  overloading, if they do not extend each other
B.  overriding, if one class extends another
C.  overloading, if one class extends another
D.  inheritance    
E.  overriding
```

Comment: This smells an awful lot like a homework problem. What do *you* think?

Comment: @2h2h2h do you plan to write on SO all the questions in your assignment?

Comment: I really hope no teacher listed those as the five possible answers.

Comment: No this is my exam document

Comment: option  E. overriding

Comment: @2h2h2h: I recommend answering StriplingWarrior's question: What do *you* think? (And why?)

Comment: Go to google, search for those terms, read, learn! You don't want us to give you answers like this, I know it.

Comment: I really need help because overriding has same name but different signature

Comment: @2h2h2h: No, it doesn't -- read up on overriding and overloading.

Comment: I think you should read what overriding is again.

Comment: Here is a clear and simple page you can read about [Overriding vs. Overloading](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/overriding-and-overloading-in-java-with-examples/).

Comment: Looking at any definition of these should show you what you are looking for: [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading),
[overriding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding),
[inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 0):

Overriding shoud be the answer for my crazy question